# Show ADS on the bottom of the page when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the Google Ads on the bottom of my website, but I want it to appear only when the mouse hovers (or clicks) an arrow icon. I don't know if you understand what I mean. **I want the AD to slide from nowhere when the mouse hovers an arrow on the bottom of the page.**

Which JS and CSS codes do I need for that function?

My codes now:

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer"> <center><script src="http://fanscity.eu/ads/728x90.js"></script></center> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: post the markup for arrow.

Comment: @sanki How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ptLx8xhe/4/)

**UPDATE :**

HTML

```
<div id="footer">footer</div>
<img id="img" src="arrow.png"/>
```

CSS

```
#footer{
    display:none;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#666;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0
}    
#img{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0  
}
```

JS

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var ishover = false;
    $(document).on("mouseover",'#footer',function(){
        ishover = true;
    }).on("mouseleave",'#footer',function(){
        $(this).stop().fadeOut();
        ishover = false;
    }).on("mouseover",'#img',function(){
        $('#footer').stop().fadeIn();
    }).on("mouseleave",'#img',function(){
        if(!ishover)
        $('#footer').stop().fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I want an Image to be on the bottom  of the page, so visitors can read 'ADS' so when they hover the image, the AD appears. How can I do that? Thanks again

Comment: Yes it was! But something doesn't work fine on my website. [look](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar)

Comment: what is the problem ? `displaying the ADS` or `$('#footer').fadeIn()\fadeOut()`?

Comment: The `fadeIn() fadeOut()` , as you can see when you hover on 'show ads' the fade blinks, I don't know if you uderstand what I mean